# Use autolayout on view added to UIWindow

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to add a subview to the `keyWindow` of the app, and position it using autolayout. However, autolayout doesn't seem to work at all, whereas setting a frame does. I want to align my view `infoSc` to the bottom of the `keyWindow` using the following code:

```
let infoSc = InfoScreenView()
infoSc.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

let keyWindow = UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow!
keyWindow.addSubview(infoSc)
keyWindow.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: infoSc, attribute: .Left, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: keyWindow, attribute: .Left, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
keyWindow.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: infoSc, attribute: .Right, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: keyWindow, attribute: .Right, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
keyWindow.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: infoSc, attribute: .Bottom, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: keyWindow, attribute: .Bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
infoSc.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: infoSc, attribute: .Height, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 100))
```

However, it appears to have a frame of `CGRectZero` using this method. Any ideas how to make this work? Ideally I'd also want to align it to something that's inside `self.view` too, but that throws an error that `self.view` is not in the view hierarchy of `keyWindow`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you need to draw on the entire window, here is code to do it (in this example I am in the `AppDelegate`, so window is the `AppDelegate.window` property).

```
func tryToDrawOnTheWindow()
{
    if let window = window, view = window.rootViewController?.view
    {
            print("I have a root view")

            let infoSc = InfoScreenView(frame: view.frame)
            let count = view.subviews.count
            view.insertSubview(infoSc, atIndex: count)
            infoSc.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            let height = NSLayoutConstraint(item: infoSc, attribute: .Height, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: view, attribute: .Height, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
            let width = NSLayoutConstraint(item: infoSc, attribute: .Width, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: view, attribute: .Width, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
            let offset = NSLayoutConstraint(item: infoSc, attribute: .Top, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: view, attribute: .Top, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
            print([height, width, offset])
            view.addConstraints([height, width, offset])
    }
    else
    {
        print("No root view on which to draw")
    }
}
```

This will let you draw on top of whatever is in the view hierarchy.  In my test app, I added a textfield and a blue rect, and the overlay was orange with 40% opacity.  Bear in mind that by default the overlay view will consume all taps in this case.

Comment: I used the window because my `InfoScreenView` has to be on top of all views (including any navbars etc). In a basic sense it draws circles to highlight areas on the screen. Your code will work, but will be constrained by the 'view' which may be contained inside a nav controller/tab bar controller.

Comment: Ok, updated the answer to reflect what you are trying to do.

Comment: How is this the accepted answer? It doesn't add the subview to the window, it adds it to the view of the root controller of the window which is not what the question was.

Answer (score 0):

Place and call a method below, based on **David S's** answer, where you want, passing your **view** as variable.

```
func addToWindow(view : UIView) {
    guard let delegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate, let window = delegate.window!, let topView = window.rootViewController?.view else {
        print("No root view on which to draw")
        return
    }

    print("I have a root view")

    let count = topView.subviews.count
    topView.insertSubview(view, at: count)
    view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    let height = NSLayoutConstraint(item: view, attribute: .height, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: topView, attribute: .height, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
    let width = NSLayoutConstraint(item: view, attribute: .width, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: topView, attribute: .width, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
    let pinToTop = NSLayoutConstraint(item: view, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: topView, attribute: .top, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
    print([height, width, pinToTop])
    topView.addConstraints([height, width, pinToTop])
}
```