# Adding a UIView to a UITableViewController with NSLayoutConstraints programmatically with Swift 4

Tags: ios, uiview, nslayoutconstraint, swift4, xcode9

I'm attempting to add a UIView with NSLayoutConstraints but I keep getting an uncaught exception of type NSException error. The main reason I'm doing it with code instead of in the storyboard is I want it to be above the Navigation bar on the UITableViewController.

Here is the code I currently have.

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    let mainWindow: UIWindow = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow!

    let newView = UIView()
    newView.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkAqua
    newView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    mainWindow.addSubview(newView)

    let viewHeight = NSLayoutConstraint(item: newView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.height, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 100)
    let viewWidth = NSLayoutConstraint(item: newView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.width, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 100)
    let viewLeft = NSLayoutConstraint(item: newView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.left, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: mainWindow, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.left, multiplier: 1, constant: 40)
    let viewTop = NSLayoutConstraint(item: newView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.top, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: mainWindow, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.top, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)

    newView.addConstraints([viewHeight, viewWidth, viewLeft, viewTop])
}
```

If I take out the `viewLeft` and `viewTop` it will run okay since the `toItem:` is nil in `NSLayoutConstraint`. But I think the problem has something to do with that `toItem:` I've tried using `self.view` and `mainWindow` but it keeps throwing the error.

I've seen lots of examples of how to do this and I'm pretty much copying them as far as I can tell, but none of them were Swift 4 so I'm wondering if something changed in Swift 4.

Any help would be great! Thank you.

Error Message:

> libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
>   (lldb)

Comment: Can you update your question and include the actual error you're seeing? Thanks!

Comment: Okay, added. Thank you :)

Comment: Oh! Just saw something... look at where your'e adding the constraint. I don't think you're allowed to add constraints to a UIWindow... look here -- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38208215/use-autolayout-on-view-added-to-uiwindow

Comment: I had tried it with `self.view` too, and got the same error.

Comment: Everything about what you're doing is wrong. You cannot add a view to the main window. The highest view available to you is the root view controller's view.

Comment: Interesting, how would I access the root view controller?

Comment: I don't know why you'd want to. - You are not reading the error message correctly. Scroll up. Don't you see this: "When added to a view, the constraint's items must be descendants of that view (or the view itself). This will crash if the constraint needs to be resolved before the view hierarchy is assembled."

Comment: No, that was the full error message I received.

Comment: No it wasn't. Trust me.

Comment: Matt, just doubled check, that is for sure the full message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried with self.view instead of main window and with the different style of layout constraints. Just try this Jason Brady.

```swift
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let newView = UIView()
    newView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    newView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    self.view.addSubview(newView)


    newView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leftAnchor, constant: 40).isActive = true
    newView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    newView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
    newView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
}
```

Comment: Exactly what I was going to say! :)

Comment: Hey Selvam, worked great, I hadn't seen this method on the other ones. Thank you for teaching it to me. Only thing I notice is that puts the `newView` below the Navigation Bar, is there a way to put it on top?

Comment: //self.view.addSubview(newView)
  let parentView = self.navigationController?.view
  parentView?.addSubview(newView)

Comment: Sorry Selvam, I was wrong. 0 is measured from the bottom of the Nav Bar, thank you so much for being so helpful.